# Stash Issue Not Getting Values In IE 8/10 & Safari

Tags: stash

I'm having a huge issue, not sure what caused it though. I'm using stash to get 2 values of a users account. I've been using Stash for the past 3 months to load these values into a form with no issue. This morning it no longer works in IE or Safari however works correctly in Firefox and Chrome. Any suggestions on what I should look for or what have caused this to stop working? No updates have been done to Stash or ExpressionEngine.

Comment: Some additional details, apparently in IE it's {exp:stash:get} is working correctly if the set is on the same page, but if you stash a variable it's not loading on a following page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently my server date/time was off which was causing an issue with Stash from being able to load those in Internet Explorer and Safari.